# Alternative to this query to run under MariaDb 10.1

Tags: sql, mariadb, window-functions

This query works as expected under Mysql 8, but MariaDB 10.1 is used on my server. Do you know if an alternative exists to this ? And how to achieve it ?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
  *,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hs.`ending_hour`, hs.`starting_hour`))) OVER (ORDER BY hs.starting_hour RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '12' HOUR following)) AS tot
FROM
  time_table hs
  WHERE hs.`starting_hour` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND hs.`ending_hour` <= NOW()
 ORDER BY hs.`starting_hour` ASC
 ) t1
  HAVING tot >= '14:00:00' 
 ;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5rXH8Xa3gZcnUsP8xuewiR/0)

The problem is `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL` on `OVER` window function doesn't exists under MariaDB at this moment.

Thank you

Sample data:

```
        id  starting_hour        ending_hour          
------  -------------------  ---------------------
     1  2018-09-02 06:00:00  2018-09-02 08:30:00  
     2  2018-09-02 08:30:00  2018-09-02 10:00:00  
     4  2018-09-03 11:00:00  2018-09-03 15:00:00  
     5  2018-09-04 15:30:00  2018-09-04 16:00:00  
     6  2018-09-04 16:15:00  2018-09-04 17:00:00  
     7  2018-09-19 00:00:00  2018-09-19 03:00:00  
     8  2018-09-19 04:00:00  2018-09-19 15:00:00  
     9  2018-09-20 00:00:00  2018-09-20 22:01:00  
    10  2018-10-21 12:00:00  2018-10-21 11:00:00  
    11  2018-10-29 09:09:00  2018-10-29 10:10:00  
    12  2018-10-09 02:10:00  2018-10-09 14:00:00
```

In my use case id 7, 8 and 9 are the results.

RE-EDIT

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff answer's, this is the corrected query.
But finally doesn't work as expected. Increasing `INTERVAL 50 DAY` return non wanted rows that MySQL window function doesn't.

```
SELECT hs.*,
       (
       SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hs2.ending_hour, hs2.starting_hour))))
        FROM hours_sailor hs2
        WHERE hs2.starting_hour >= DATE_SUB(hs.starting_hour, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND hs2.starting_hour <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
      ) AS duration
FROM `time_table` hs
WHERE hs.`starting_hour` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND hs.`ending_hour` <= NOW()
HAVING duration >= '14:00:00' 
ORDER BY hs.starting_hour ASC;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: sorry for that i edit my post

Comment: Why cant you simply update the Mariadb server ? Alternative solutions would be extremely verbose, possibly utilizing user-defined variables.

Comment: As far as i know the latest MariaDB version (10.4 in alpha release) did not implement it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this using a correlated subquery.  I think this is the equivalent logic:

```
SELECT hs.*,
       (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hs2.ending_hour, hs2.starting_hour)))
        FROM time_table hs2
        WHERE hs2.starting_hour >= hs.starting_hour - INTERVAL '12' HOUR AND
              hs2.starting_hour <= hs.starting_hour + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
      ) AS tot
FROM time_table hs
WHERE hs.starting_hour > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND
      hs.ending_hour <= NOW()
HAVING tot >= '14:00:00' 
ORDER BY hs.starting_hour ASC;
```

EDIT:

If you also want the timing restriction for the "range" calculation, you need to include it in the subquery.  This filtering is built into the window function, but it is more often a hinderance than feature:

```
SELECT hs.*,
       (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hs2.ending_hour, hs2.starting_hour)))
        FROM time_table hs2
        WHERE hs2.starting_hour >= hs.starting_hour - INTERVAL '12' HOUR AND
              hs2.starting_hour <= hs.starting_hour + INTERVAL '12' HOUR AND
              hs2.starting_hour > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND
              hs2.ending_hour <= NOW()
      ) AS tot
FROM time_table hs
WHERE hs.starting_hour > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND
      hs.ending_hour <= NOW()
HAVING tot >= '14:00:00' 
ORDER BY hs.starting_hour ASC;
```

Comment: You my savior, it look like exactly what I'am looking for. Just to be clear i'll update my question with the corrected query because this is not 100% Mysql/MariaDb compatible.

But just thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my enthusiasm quick answer but i realize there is a problem, if you increase `INTERVAL 50` extra rows coming that mysql window function's doesn't

Comment: @klesk44 . . . That is because your outer `WHERE` clause would apply to your original version.  If you want the same overall limits, you need to apply them in the subquery.

Comment: Is it possible to update your query to explain your answer ? @gordon

Comment: Ok I've done this but i think I don't understand because the results are the same with or without this subquery where clause. with `INTERVAL 50 DAY` it seems relevant. But with `INTERVAL 100 DAY` it doesn't. 

With 100 day interval, result shoud be the same as with 50 (that what Mysql8 returns)

Comment: So the only solution yet is to migrate to MySQL 8 ?